# Jquery Animation through pictures

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am learning jquery to make some cool animation. Right now I have been given an assignment on pictures which expands, contract and opacity changes as well , in the end it hides.

Here is my code:

```
function play_pic1()
{
    var div = $("#img");
    div.animate({width:0},2000);
    div.animate({width:1100,opacity:0},4000);
    div.animate({opacity:1},4000);
    div.hide(4000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
         play_pic1();
         play_pic1();       
});
```

The problem is it only works for one image, when I try to insert second image the second image become static.

I used Loops and Function but nothing helped. Kindly help me overcome this issue.

Comment: @Mistu4u Please don't use the homework-tag. It's obsolete, as the tag-description clearly states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the element you want to animate as a parameter of the function , e.g.

```
function play_pic1(element)
{
    var div = $(element);
    div.animate({width:0},2000)
       .animate({width:1100,opacity:0},4000)
       .animate({opacity:1},4000)
       .hide(4000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
         play_pic1("#img1");
         play_pic1("#img2");       
});
```

---

After OP clarification: if you need to have sequential animation over different elements you could use `Deferred objects` like so

**Example JSBin**:  http://jsbin.com/ilisug/1/edit

```
function animate(el)
{
    var div = $(el);
    return div.animate({width:0},2000)
       .animate({width:300,opacity:0},2000)
       .animate({opacity:1},2000)
       .hide(2000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var dfd = $.Deferred(), 
        chain = dfd;

    var slide = ['#el1', '#el2', '#el3'];

    $.map(slide, function(el) {
        chain = chain.pipe(function() {
            return animate(el).promise();
        });
    });

    chain.done(function() {
       alert('done')
    });

    return dfd.resolve();
});
```

Comment: Thank for helping, This post helped me to grasp the chaining method , also the functions. But still Both pictures are animating together, i want to make a temporal presentation. Like a slider timer base.

Comment: One last thing i want to ask more, it is that three objects are visible at a time, i want to visible only the animated object other two should be hidden and consume no space at container

Comment: just hide them all via css (`display: none`) and show each element as first statement of your animation function

Comment: in jQuery just do `$('#brain').clone(true)`: this will copy not only the brain element but also the handlers (ideas) associated :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't retrieve all your div by one ID : only one occurence of an id is possible in an HTML document.

You should use a class (`<div class=img></div>`) and replace

```
var div = $("#img");
```

with

```
var div = $(".img");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = $("#img");
```

above statement says only #img will be referenced. when you add an image dynamically, you will  have to modify your code a bit. try passing an ID to this function and apply animate on that. something like

```
function play_pic1(id)
{
    var div = $(id);
    div.animate({width:0},2000);
    div.animate({width:1100,opacity:0},4000);
    div.animate({opacity:1},4000);
    div.hide(4000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#img` will be applicable for only the first image, you'll have to pass the selector as an argument to `play_pic1()`

```
function play_pic1(elem)
{
    var div = $(elem);
    //your code here
}

$(document).ready(function(){
         play_pic1("#img"); //pass the img selector to play_pic1
         play_pic1("#img2");       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is, using sameID for multiple elements `#img` will only affect the first element.

instead this you can use class `.img` and this code:

```
function play_pic1(){
 $(".img").each(function(){
   var div = $(this);
   div.animate({width:0},2000);
   div.animate({width:1100,opacity:0},4000);
   div.animate({opacity:1},4000);
   div.hide(4000); 
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   play_pic1();     
});
```

try to use class `$(".img")`

Comment: Yup i got the point, still two images are animating simontanously, i want one to come after another.